# Is this correct: simple KL Divergence on uniform distribution

Tags: integration, cayley-klein

P1 is uniform of [0, 0.5], P2 is uniform of [0, 1]

What is the KL-divergence(P1 || P2)?

Attempt:

[image]

KL(P1||P2) = integral of log(1/(1/2)) = integral of log(2) from 0 to 0.5 = log(2) /2 .

KL(P2||P1) = KL(P1 || P2)